# Spring not injecting bean if it is instantiated on definition

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a session scoped bean defined like so:

```
<!-- this is where the serviceImpl bean is defined -->
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/*-core-context.xml"/>

<bean id="myBean" class="com.company.Bean">
    <property name="service" ref="serviceImpl"/>
</bean>
```

Now inside the bean I have defined a default value for the injected service like so:

```
public class Bean {

    private Service service = new NullService();

    public void setService(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to provide the ability to optionally inject the service and if you choose not to the `Bean` will use the `NullService` implementation which simply does nothing, not affecting the bean logic in any way.

The problem is that for some reason the `serviceImpl` is never injected and I always end up with the `NullService` implementation.

So is there some spring setting or feature which prevents it from injecting it ? Or do you have any other ideas on why this might happen ?

---

**More info**

This is the setter that spring uses to inject the service:

```
public void setPermissionsService(PermissionService permissionsService) {
    this.permissionsService = permissionsService;

    System.out.println("setting permissions service to: " + permissionsService.getClass().getName());
    if (this.permissionsService instanceof NoopPermissionsServiceImpl) {
        System.out.println("NULL IMPLEMENTATION");
    }
    else if (this.permissionsService instanceof PermissionServiceImpl) {
        System.out.println("CORRECT IMPLEMENTATION");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("WHAT ?!?!");
    }
}
```

It prints `"WHAT ?!?!"`.

So it turns out spring sets it to a dynamic proxy [`$Proxy859`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html). Is there a way to see the class the proxy is proxying ?

Comment: Please provide the missing relevant implementation details. My questions: How do you instantiate the Bean? If not via Spring, this explains it. Another thing could be that your serviceImpl is the NullService, but I can only guess

Comment: You say `Bean` is session scoped (not in the declaration but never mind). How do you obtain it? Is it created by Spring? If you aren't sure, add c-tor and place breakpoint there to see whether it's the Spring that instantiates and populates it. BTW nice usage of Null Object pattern, consider making `NullService` singleton.

Comment: I can't think of anything else relevant actually, what do you need exactly ? Further `Bean` details or something about the service ?

Comment: @Tomasz Its created by spring and it actually calls the `setService(Service service)` when it instantiates the context, I can't see with which implementation however as it call it with `$Proxy859`, I'm debugging it right now, but I tought I could ask if its something simple.

Comment: @pvblivs some details: my favorite color is blue :), what do you need details on ? thanks.

Comment: Not simple, because what you have posted should work. So debugging is a great idea...

Comment: @pvblivs I saw it sorry :) I'll edit my question

Comment: Implement toString() on both your service implementations, and have setPermissionsService print the result of service.toString(). That'll give you a quick and dirty way of finding the actual implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I see to your problem is to reverse-engineer this a bit. Do something like that in the same spring.xml:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.company.Bean">
  <property name="service" ref="testServiceImpl"/>
</bean>

<bean id="testServiceImpl" class="com.company.TestServiceImpl" />
```

Then implement the `TestServiceImpl` with simple debug messages indicating that construction and your service call is actually working. This *has* to work. If it does you have a problem with your original service definition. If not you have a problem in your Bean.

Try to narrow the problem to a simpler. And then work into the simpler problem.

Good luck!

Comment: I saw your answer after I actually found the problem, but yes this would have worked if I tried it. The problem was that I had another `bean` defined in another context like this `<bean id="bean" class="com.company.Bean">` and that one had no service injected. So actually the bean that was using `bean` always received the instance with the null service. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Dang, I had the same problem, but strangely, the child application context, which did indeed have a bean with the same name, was not being loaded just yet. It's as if Spring introspected the child context even though it wasn't being loaded. This is Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be lacking a definition for your `serviceImpl` bean in your configuration. Something like

```
<bean id="serviceImpl" class="com.company.ServiceImpl" />
```

Comment: No its there I just haven't posted it. If it was't there I would be seeing exceptions. This is a valid answer though given the information I provided so thanks.

Comment: I see this gets voted up, but it is not the problem since if the service was not defined I would be seeing exceptions when spring tried to instantiate `Bean`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `instanceof` use [Class.isAssignableFrom(Class)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29)